# How to update label text in for each Loop.

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of tabs that I am loading data in parallel. I want to let the user know that a certain tab is loading but when I set the text of the label it is only updated on the first time.

```
<label class="col-1">Loading Tab...{{tabN}}</label>

 this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
 this.tabN = tab.name;
 })
```

Comment: Please provide code where you load the tabs (even better - a [mcve]). Currently it looks like you set the `tabN` in a synchronous cycle, so the expected output would be the last name of the tab in the array.

Comment: You can use *ngFor in component  HTML section in angular

Comment: @Krypt yes you are correct I was thinking that the label being in a for each statement then it would see each name of the tab as it loops through.

Comment: At this point you should only see on the wepage the last item of tabs array. To make an animation you should make intervals between iterations. You can use setInterval method or as I pefer - GSAP framework, perfect for animations of any kind.

Comment: I have created a loop however how can I send 'this' to my function? const test = function loop(); Inside my loop function 'this' is undefined. I need to be able to set this.text inside the function